# What is the verb form of "trajectory"?

Tags: word-request, verb-forms

What is the verb form of **trajectory**?

I looked up **trajectorize** but there's no such word.

Comment: In English, nouns don't have "verb forms".  Sometimes there are verbs with related meanings.  Sometimes there are several different verbs with related but different meanings that can be formed from a noun. In this case I have no idea what meaning you think a verb form of "trajectory" would be.  Do you mean "throw"?  Or do you mean "follow a trajectory"?

Comment: Who says *trajectorise (/-ize)* is not a word? It's sounds perfectly fine to me. Note that no dictionary can ever tell you something is not a word.

Comment: Because it's absence from a dictionary implies that the word is very rarely used and so using it would cause confusion.  I don't know what "trajectorize" is supposed to mean.  Learners should use words that have currency in English, wherever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nouns in English don't have "verb forms".

"Trajectory" is the path that a projectile follows under gravity.  To put something onto a trajectory you "project" it (stress on the second syllable). Or in simple language, you "throw" it.

You can also say "follow a trajectory".  In English it is often better to use a phrase rather than a single verb.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google.com, *traject*, meaning *thrown across*, was an earlier version.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/traject) defines *traject* as

[ truh-jekt ]

> verb (used with object) Archaic
> to transport, transmit, or transpose.

Comment: Note the usage note "archaic".  This means that the word is not used in modern English anymore, and learners should not use this word (without good reason).